# How to fix "Cookie Security: Cookie not Sent Over SSL ( 4720 )" in Java Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, ssl, https

We have a JAVA Spring Boot application. On doing the scan we got this vulnerability

"Cookie Security: Cookie not Sent Over SSL ( 4720 )"

How to fix this from the code level? How to enable the cookie encryption while returning the response in Java code?

Is the decryption automatically is taken care?

Comment: Please add way more information. Please edit your question and tell us something about your specific situation and problem. If you have code also post code snippets. [How To: Ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What kind of scan you did exactly?

Comment: DAST and SAST scan @VitalyChura